# how to passed value from mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in php so please help me here
I have one page for collect customer details and i did successfully 
from databse table i want to pass 2 value 
1- amount 2- personid
**Table-**
CREATE TABLE personal_info(
MTrackid bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
MAmount varchar(50)

---

i write mysql query to pass value

```html
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","testdb","root@123");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","testdb","root@123");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT MTrackid,MAmount FROM personal_info");
while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $trackid = isset($_GET['MTrackid']) ? $_GET['MTrackid'] : '';


}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and this is the code where i want to pass and show value

```html
$TranTrackid=isset($_POST['MTrackid']) ? $_POST['MTrackid'] : '';
```

So please tell me where i am wrong and how to pass it and who where i want..

Thank in advance

Comment: Your question makes little sense, are you trying to get the data on one page and show it on another or what?

Comment: @Epodax no both are in one page request.php page name

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to save the value from the SQL.
Then you should replace `$_GET` with `$rowval`. Because in `$rowval` will be your mysql result.

```
while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     if(isset($rowval['MTrackid'])) {
        $trackid = $rowval['MTrackid'];
        echo $trackid;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Tobias
but i want to show(pass) the value at same page 
1- i want to take data from database table and then with help of query i want to display
Code- $TranTrackid=isset($_POST['MTrackid']) ? $_POST['MTrackid'] : '';

Comment: You can add `echo $trackid;`

Comment: while($_GET = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $trackid = isset($_GET['MTrackid']) ? $_GET['MTrackid'] : '';  echo $trackid; }

Comment: But why do you want to show $_GET parameter when you catch the data from a databse?

Comment: thnks...what should i do over here(at this place i want to show)
'$TranTrackid=isset($_POST['MTrackid']) ? $_POST['MTrackid'] : '';'

Comment: i my uknowledge $_GET used for taking data from database table .. that why i used it . my 1st step to take data from database table with help of procedure. 2nd step that value i want to show in same php page. code already show you if is any modification please tell me ..

Comment: Good .. but what should i do with this code-- $TranTrackid=isset($_POST['MTrackid']) ? $_POST['MTrackid'] : ''; I want that value over here not in script

Comment: You dont need it. You can delete it.

Comment: just try to understand i want to show script `$trackid`value at this particular place where this code is belong  `$TranTrackid=isset($_POST['MTrackid']) ? $_POST['MTrackid'] : '';`

Comment: at same page ....


`<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","testdb","root@123");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","testdb","root@123");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT MTrackid,MAmount FROM personal_info");
while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $trackid = isset($_GET['MTrackid']) ? $_GET['MTrackid'] : '';


}
mysql_close($con);


$TranTrackid=isset($_POST['MTrackid']) ? $_POST['MTrackid'] : '';
?>`